# Error 1449 in MySQL - Alternative Solutions?

Tags: mysql

Recently, I deleted a user account in MySQL assigned to my former boss. Then, some database functions like deleting records from tables he made weren't working, giving the following error:

```
#1449 - There is no '*username*'@'localhost' registered
```

Now, I added a new user with the same name (and diff. password) and it works fine with no errors. But, is there way to resolve this *without* an placeholder user account?

Comment: How did you delete his user? From what I remember, there are multiple ways to delete users in MySQL, and not all of them are equally effective.

Comment: Straight from the "users" table in the mysql table via phpMyAdmin. Is there a better way?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I would usually use `DROP USER`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove and re-add the [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) for the affected tables. (I used phpMyAdmin to do this).

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing the DEFINER of the function

First login to mysql as `root@localhost`

Then, substitute `root@localhost` as the DEFINER

```
UPDATE mysql.proc SET definer='root@localhost'
WHERE definer = '*username*@localhost';
```

In fact, you can look at all DEFINERs like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) DefinerCount,definer,type
FROM mysql.proc GROUP BY definer,type;
```

This will show you how many functions and procedures each user owns. If any other the reported DEFINERs no longer exist or are invalid, you can make `root@localhost` inherit them.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The queries work, but no rows are affected. I was logged in as root (and obviously replaced ***username*** with the real username :) ). Any ideas?